# Calling Team Foundation Server(TFS) APIs via SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, tfs

I am creating my first ASP.NET MVC project. I have started with connecting TFS and adding bugs in to TFS via C#.

```
var tfsURI = new Uri("http://test:8080/tfs");
var networkCredential1 = new NetworkCredential("test", "test!");

ICredentials credential = (ICredentials)networkCredential1;
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential winCred = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(credential);
VssCredentials vssCredentials = new VssCredentials(winCred);

using (TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsURI, vssCredentials))
{
    collection.EnsureAuthenticated();
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = collection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
    Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["Test"];
    WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Bug"];

    WorkItem Defect = new WorkItem(workItemType);
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\\Document.docx");
    Attachment tfsAttachment = new Attachment(fi.FullName);
    Defect.Attachments.Add(tfsAttachment);

    Defect.Title = "Testing from VS to TFS Bug";
    Defect.Description = "Testing from VS to entered Bug in to TFS.";
    Defect.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = "Test";

    Defect.Save();
}
```

This code shown above works fine.

But is it possible to achieve same result using a SQL Server stored procedure? Is there any way to connect to TFS and add bug in to TFS using a stored procedure?

I have my database and from sql stored procedure I wanted to connect to TFS and create WorkItem. Via C# I have done as seen above example. But I need any example if same thing can be achieved from a stored procedure.

Comment: In the comments on the answer @PatrickLu-MSFT, you said: _'depends on entry in one the tables'_ You already have working code in C# to add WorkItems to TFS -- why not also use C# and ADO.NET to issue a SQL query and get your table data directly in your C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Solution i found after lot of research as SP is not possible. solution is to create Window Service. which will run in background for every 5 Min and will monitor entry in to SQl Table (my case) if entry exist for Bug will create Ticket in TFS. 
this is the simple, best solution as of now without compromising on performance or anything.

Answer (score 8):

Update:

You could call a web service from SQL CLR. Some tutorials maybe helpful:

- [How to create a SQL CLR stored procedure to get data from a web service and insert results into a SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536835/how-to-create-a-sql-clr-stored-procedure-to-get-data-from-a-web-service-and-inse)
- [Generate JSON Data Using Web Service And SQL Server Stored Procedure](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generate-json-data-using-web-service-and-sql-server-stored-procedure/)

---

No, the only database that's designed for user querying is the warehouse database. The others are explicitly not supported and should not be directly queried.

Do not **make any changes to the TFS Databases directly**, otherwise you may **lose the support** from Microsoft.

Please take a look at this similar question here: [Add a stored procedure to TFS database](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/59950845-afea-40e6-9f97-3cc1b0d63a76/add-a-stored-procedure-to-tfs-database?forum=tfsreporting)

In addition to using client API, you could also use Rest API in TFS to do the something.

[Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)

```
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=5.0
```

Comment: hello, actually i do not want to change TFS Databases directly, i only wanted to connect TFS and create WortItem in TFS via SQL Stored Procedure.....it is posssible...?  can i call TFS Rest APIs from Stored procedure......

Comment: i do not want to add Stored procedure to TFS.  i only wants to connect TFS and add Workitem into TFS but not like C# but via my Stored Procedure.

Comment: i have my database and depend on entry in one of table i want to create workItem via SQL Stored Procedure....

Comment: @user2813740 Sorry for the misunderstanding, please see my update reply. This is really not a common scenario. I have to say, I'm not be familiar with this and haven't test it. But have shared some tutorials which maybe helpful. Besides, suggest you use C# or powershell to handle the TFS  connection and create WorkItem.  It's more simply.

Comment: @user2813740 Sorry forget to save the update, you could try to call a web service from SQL CLR. Some tutorials maybe helpful in the update answer. Didn't find a way to directly call TFS Rest API through SQL Stored Procedure. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for reply ... i can not use CLR because of performance issue.... i found best i can create window service which will run in background...